# Grouping rows from a single day into a count - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count

I've been trying to work through this problem for a bit, and clearly I'm missing something (probably something obvious).

I'm trying to group rows from a single day into a count. So the output should look like this:

```
Date         Count
2009-09-12   2
2009-09-13   5
2010-01-09   4
```

...and so on.

My current SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_table` GROUP BY `date`;
```

And outputs data that looks like this:

```
Date        Count
2009-09-12  1
2009-09-12  1
2009-09-13  1
2009-09-13  1
2009-09-13  1
2009-09-13  1
2009-09-13  1
```

...and so on.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that `date` is really a `datetime` and it has a time component.  To get just the date, use the `date()` function:

```
SELECT date(`date`) as `date`, COUNT(*)
FROM `sales_flat_table`
GROUP BY date(`date`);
```

Comment: And that was the missing component! Thank you!!